# Ability to track the usage of a Web Component

Tags: polymer, web-component, tracking

I have created a library of UI Web Components using Polymer 3.x for a client, and the client would like to track the usage of components across various applications, is there any way to track the usage of Web Components?

Answer (score 0):

Investigate how Google tracks sites, with that code snippet on nearly every site.

Then call it from your WebComponent code.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs